# Not getting input in scheduled event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda which gets triggered by lambda cloudwatch rule. This is the cloudwatch rule created via cloudformation

```
Resources:
  CloudWatchRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub CloudWatchRule-${Stage}
      Description: "Scheduled event to fetch keys for score generation every hour"
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(2 minutes)"
      Targets:
        - Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [FetcherLambda, Arn]
          Id: "CloudWatchEvent"
          Input: '{"hours": 3}'

  CloudWatchRulePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: FetcherLambda
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt: [CloudWatchRule, Arn]
```

I can see in the console that the input is there in Constant(Json) field.

But in the handler, when I am logging I am getting empty event,

```
public Void handleRequest(final ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent, final Context context) {
        log.info("Received event: {}", scheduledEvent);
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting a log as
`Received event: {}`

Am I missing something or is there anything else needed to get the input here

Comment: This looks like a wrong log line, as it's displaying {}, it should do the replacement and not display {} in any scenario. Could you try logging         log.info("Received event: " + scheduledEvent); ?

Comment: @Yayotrón I tried this statment `log.info("Received event: " + scheduledEvent);`, got the same result `Received event: {}`.  It seems {} is for the empty event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are using the `ScheduledEvent` class as your input. When you specify the input from a rule you do not get any of the rest of the schedule data (from [AWS::Events::Rule Target - Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-input)):

> If you use this property, nothing from the event text itself is passed to the target.

In order to get the data you are expecting you need the class to be something that will be serializable from the input you specify.

Comment: Changing SceduledEvent to Map<String, String> worked. Thanks a lot for help. Was stuck here from quite a time.

Comment: It is worked for me when I use Dictionary in C# lambda, I don't know what is the intention for ScheduledEvent class, Got null every time when i using ScheduledEvent. Thanks @Nitika